# How to remove multiple characters at once using regexp_replace() in Hive?

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql, regexp-replace

I'm trying to cleanup my data in a Hive table. I need to replace some characters in a column but I'm unable to figure out how to remove multiple characters at once in using `regexp_replace()` in Hive SQL.

The below is straightforward and works as expected:

```
select regexp_replace('abc-de-ghi', '-','');
```

and outputs:
`abcdefghi`

But I don't know how to clean up a string with different characters in it:

```
select regexp_replace('abc-de/ghi@jkl:mn#op', <i-dont-know-what-goes-here>,'');
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `'[-/@:#]'` template with character set (in the brackets) you want to remove:

```
select regexp_replace('abc-de/ghi@jkl:mn#op','[-/@:#]','');
```

Result:

```
OK
abcdeghijklmnop
Time taken: 4.656 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```